# delphi get iOS deviceToken

Tags: ios, delphi, devicetoken

Delphi 10 Seattle
iOS failed to get DeviceToken,
iOS Version 10.1.
the code:

```
        implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.PushEvents1DeviceRegistered(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Device Registered');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
end;

procedure TForm1.PushEvents1DeviceTokenReceived(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Device Token Received');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
end;

procedure TForm1.PushEvents1DeviceTokenRequestFailed(Sender: TObject;
  const AErrorMessage: string);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Device Token Request Failed');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(AErrorMessage);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
end;

procedure TForm1.PushEvents1PushReceived(Sender: TObject;
  const AData: TPushData);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Device push received');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(AData.Message);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
end;

end.
```

result:
Device Token Request Failed

How to solve this problem?